# Gluint of one Texture changes when loading other textures

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

When starting my app, I load a texture for a loading screen first. While the loading screen is displayed, I then load all the other textures, sounds, and set up everything for the app to run. Strangely though, while loading my other textures, the GLuint of the loading screen texture suddenly changes and the loading screen displays the wrong image (and crashes shortly after).

My _texLoadingScreen variable only gets assigned once, when the app starts to load the texture in the first place and it gets the value 1.
While loading all the other textures, the value jumps around from 0 to 18 and other values even though _texLoadingScreen never gets assigned anything new!?

Am I hitting some kind of limits on my one texture unit with assigning too many textures?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you got a problem with how you derive pointers from your variables. We can only guess without you giving us your code, though.

Comment: Hm... Okay, but what code in particular. The code that loads all my other textures? Plus the one that loads the original texture?